# Switch from Desktop to Mobile version in PHP

Tags: php, android, iphone, mobile, desktop

I am using the following php to switch between mobile and desktop versions of my site

```
$mobile_browser = '0';

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}    

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows') > 0) {
    $mobile_browser = 0;
}

if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
   // do something
}
else {
   // do something else
}
```

Should it be if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'OperaMini')>0)

or should it be if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0)

I get a debug error using ALL_HTTP, but the error goes away when I use HTTP_USER_AGENT

Here is the debug error, as follows: Debug Notice: Undefined index: ALL_HTTP in header.php on line 29

Comment: As there is no `ALL_HTTP` in your header, and your listening for user agents, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is probably what you're after.

Comment: If `ALL_HTTP` gives an error, then it's probably *not* the right solution. I have also never heard of `$_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']`, it's not a typical key.

Comment: `ALL_HTTP` is a part of ASP for getting all headers, it does'nt exist in PHP.

Comment: Hello, you might benefit from using get_browser : http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: I found this solution orginaly from here http://stackoverflow.com/q/10935710/1492462

Comment: @user1909426 - that would require a rather extensive and updated browscap.ini file.

Comment: Thanks guys. I believe all of you helped alot. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ALL_HTTP is an IIS (Microsoft Server) variable.  See: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  ALL_HTTP is for ASP (Active Server Pages), and you're using PHP (PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor)

$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] will return the User Agent, which sounds like what you want based on your question, so use: if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'OperaMini')>0)

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is what I was after. I Appreciate your advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off with code from [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com)

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile');
?>
```

> Tablets Android tablets, iPads, Kindle Fires and PlayBooks are not detected by design. To add support for tablets, add |android|ipad|playbook|silk to the first regex.